# Java advanced Enum with an abstract method and used for branching

Tags: java, oop, enums

I'm new to java and came across some advanced Enum code in my organization. 
I am familiar with enums defined as follows: `public enum someList { VALUE1, VALUE2, ..}`

But in the advanced enum that I came across, a lot more seems to be going on..

```
/**
 * Defines ways to compare records in {@link ApplicationStatus} to see if they
 * are the same.
 */
public enum SourceStatusComparisonType
{
    CONTEXT_KEY
    {
        @Override
        public boolean compareKeys(SourceStatus source, ApplicationStatus status)
        {
            return source.getContextKey() == status.getSourceContextId();
        }
    },
    DATE
    {
        @Override
        public boolean compareKeys(SourceStatus source, ApplicationStatus status)
        {
            return source.getCobDate().equals(status.getCobDate());
        }
    };

    public abstract boolean compareKeys(SourceStatus source,
            ApplicationStatus status);
}
```

Could someone enlighten me on what's going on with the abstract method that's being overridden and overloaded. I don't understand what's going on in the above. I was told this is being used to abstract away if/else blocks from the code that uses it. But I'm not sure I understand.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Minor nitpick: IMO, `compareKeys` should either act like a Comparator and return an int, or it should be renamed "equalKeys" or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each *enum* constants can be optionally followed by a class body, as specified in [JLS §8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9).

> The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly defines an anonymous class declaration (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately enclosing enum type. The class body is governed by the usual rules of anonymous classes; in particular it cannot contain any constructors.

So, it is like creating an abstract class `SourceStatusComparisonType`, with an abstract method - `compareKeys()`. You create 2 instances of that class:

```
CONTEXT_KEY = new SourceStatusComparisonType() {
        @Override
        public void compareKeys() { .. }
    };

DATE = new SourceStatusComparisonType() {
        @Override
        public void compareKeys() { .. }
    };
```

And override the abstract method for each instances. You can't have any instance, without having an implementation of that method.

Similarly, all the enum constants, must provide an implementation of the abstract method in it's respective anonymous class body. Else, you can't have that method as abstract. You have to provide a body, which will be used by default for the enum constants, that don't provide that method implementation:

```
public enum SourceStatusComparisonType
{
    CONTEXT_KEY
    {
        @Override
        public boolean compareKeys(SourceStatus source, ApplicationStatus status)
        {
            return source.getContextKey() == status.getSourceContextId();
        }
    },
    DATE
    {
        @Override
        public boolean compareKeys(SourceStatus source, ApplicationStatus status)
        {
            return source.getCobDate().equals(status.getCobDate());
        }
    },
    DEFAULT;

    public boolean compareKeys(SourceStatus source,
            ApplicationStatus status) {
//        return somedefaultvalue;
    }
}
```

So, for the first 2 constants, when you invoke `compareKeys` method, their specific implementation will be used, and for `DEFAULT`, the method defined outside will be used.

Comment: Thank you. This is immensely helpful. This seems like the part of java that isn't covered in the java book that I've been reading such as "Head First Java". It's a clever and clean approach. Could you point me to a book that speaks of such clever and clean object oriented programming design using java please? Thank you!

Comment: @TazMan Head First Java is a nice book. And don't worry, you learn clean approaches through experience, not through any book.

Comment: Could you recommend a book that covers good object oriented design?

Comment: @TazMan When you're done with head first java, you must read "Effective Java". That's the best book in the market, about Best Practices in Java. If you just want a book regarding good OO design, then you can go for Code Complete, but that would be a bit high level.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  @TazMan The confusing part about the Java enum syntax is that it feels "backwards".  Normally, you'd define an abstract class with it's `compareKey()` method (and maybe some common fields), then various subclasses that implement it.  In an Enum, one declares the classes first, then their abstract and common methods and fields.  Anybody know why Java did it this way?

Answer (score 2):

Enum type can have body like abstract methods and all enum constants should implement those abstract methods.

Look at the JSL here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2 and go to the section `Example 8.9.2-4. Enum Constants with Class Bodies`.

You even can implement an ENUM with an interface rather having a abstract method in it. Something like `public enum SourceStatusComparisonType implements StatusComparable`.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to know about Enum in Java is that they are classes, think of them as classes. As such all the object oriented design/programming concepts you have learned apply to them.

Imagine a universe of your making, in which only 3 creatures exists, a Cat and Cow and a dog. One implementation would be

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    private final String name;
    public Animal(String name) {
      this.name  = name;
    }

    public abstract String sayHello(Animal other);
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
    public Cat(String name) {
       super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello(Animal other) {
      System.out.println(this.name + " says Meow!!! to " + other.name);
    }
}

public class Cow extends Animal
{
    public Cow(String name) {
       super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello(Animal other) {
        System.out.println(this.name + " says Moo!!! to " + other.name);
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    public Dog(String name) {
       super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello(Animal other) {
        System.out.println(this.name + " says Woof!!! to " + other.name);
    }
}

public Universe {
  public List<Animal> animals;

  public Universe(List<Animal> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
  }

  public void run() {
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
      for (Animal other : animals) {
        if (other != animal) {
           animal.sayHello(other);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You are satisfied with your universe and deploy it in production. Only to find, another malicious developer has introduced a new creature to your universe, a zombie

```
public class Zombie extends Animal
{
    public Zombie(String name) {
       super(name);
    }

    public String sayHello(Animal other) {
        System.out.println(this.name + " says Arrggggg!!! to " + other.name);
        eat(other);
    }

    private void eat(Animal other) {
        System.out.println("nomm nomm " + other.name);
    }
}
```

Zombies in the guise of saying hello eat all the animals they run into. Pretty soon there will be no Cats, Dogs and Cows left. You decide to deploy version 2 of your universe to prevent this and guard against zombies

```
public Universe2 {
  public List<Animal> animals;

  public Universe(List<Animal> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
  }

  public void run() {
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
      for (Animal other : animals) {
        if (other != animal) {
           if (!(animal instanceof Zombie))
             animal.sayHello(other);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You are happy now, but you notice the cat populations decreasing, turns out cats and dogs are no longer friends, the zombies have infected their brains, you deploy version 3 of the universe.

```
public Universe3 {
  public List<Animal> animals;

  public Universe(List<Animal> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
  }

  public void run() {
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
      for (Animal other : animals) {
        if (other != animal) {
           if (!(animal instanceof Zombie) && !((animal instanceof Cat) && (animal instanceof Dog)))
             animal.sayHello(other);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this version, there are no zombies. Cats and Dogs say hello to Cows but not each other. The universe is in equilibrium but you have a nagging feeling that not everything is right with the world. You sleep on it and come to the realization that you are open to attack similar to the zombie ones, you decide to lock down the universe and implement a rewrite to start from scratch and eliminate the zombie epidemic entirely. Except you like friendly zombies that say hello.

```
public Enum Animal {

    Cat {
        @Override
        public String sayHello(Animal other) {
          System.out.println(this.name + " says Meow!!! to " + other.name);
        }
    },
    Cow {
        @Override
        public String sayHello(Animal other) {
          System.out.println(this.name + " says Moo!!! to " + other.name);
        }
    },
    Dog {
        @Override
        public String sayHello(Animal other) {
          System.out.println(this.name + " says Woof!!! to " + other.name);
        }
    },
    Zombie {
        @Override
        public String sayHello(Animal other) {
          System.out.println(this.name + " says Argggg!!! to " + other.name);
        }
    };

    private String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
       this.name.
    }

    public String sayHello(Animal other);
}


public PerfectUniverse {
  public List<Animal> animals;

  public Universe(List<Animal> animals) {
    this.animals = animals;
  }

  public void run() {
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
      for (Animal other : animals) {
        if (other != animal) {
             animal.sayHello(other);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You have eliminated the conditional if's using inheritance but locking down the extensibility by using an enumeration. You can do the same using classes, restricting access to Animal outside the package and making the derived types final. This of the enum Cat as an instance of Cat extending Animal. The derived types with overridden method avoid the need for instanceof checks with if conditionals.

Comment: Thank you so much , extremely useful and clearly explained.

Comment: Great efforts sir.